# How to position a node relative to another node using +(coordinate) syntax?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My code is :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodeTot/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=1cm},
                nodeItem/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size=1.2cm}]

    \node (t1) [nodeTot] at (0,0) {100};
    \node (t2) [nodeTot] at +(-135:2cm) {50};
    \node (t3) [nodeTot] at t2.center +(-135:2cm) {10}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The above doesn't work. I need the node t3 to be positioned relative to t2, without using `++(-135:2cm)` for t2, as I also need to set other nodes in place relative to t1. How do I achieve this?

Comment: `\path (t1) +(-135:2cm) node[nodeTot] (t2) {50};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the nodes in one path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodeTot/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=1cm},
  nodeItem/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size=1.2cm}]

  \draw (0,0) node[nodeTot](t1){100} ++(-135:2cm) node[nodeTot](t2){50} ++(-135:2cm) node[nodeTot](t3){10}; 
  \draw[->] (t1) to [bend left=50] (t3);
  \draw[<->] (t2) -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]